# Is it possible to share a session between Selenium and a LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, selenium, cookies, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to download a file from a website which requires a login process. This process can be done manually as follows:

1. Open the browser and login into the page
2. If you have the url just enter it and you will access the file.

My problem is more complex that that, and I have to do some processing to get that url with selenium. But I'm not able to download the file with the common approaches:

1. Getting the url (I get a croak which can not be escaped with try/catch).
2. Generating a javascript element and clicking it generates an exception in the website.

So my new approach would be:

1. Do the login stuff with selenium.
2. Take the cookies and headers which are done in the request.
3. Make the request with selenium.

This is how I do it:

```
use Selenium::Firefox;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Selenium::Waiter qw/wait_until/;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use File::Temp;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use Data::Dumper qw/Dumper/;


my $driver = Selenium::Firefox->new(marionette_enabled => 1 );
$driver->set_implicit_wait_timeout(3000);

$driver->get('https://example.com');

# processing and login

my $uri = 'https://example.com/myfile.tcx';

print "Downloading the following file: $url\n";

my $cookies = $driver->get_all_cookies();

# Create temporary file to download
my $tmp = File::Temp->new( TEMPLATE => 'myTemplateXXXX', SUFFIX=>'.tcx', UNLINK=>0 );

my $cookie_jar_obj = HTTP::Cookies->new(ignore_discard=>1,hide_cookie2=>1);
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar_obj );

foreach my $cookie_ref (@{$cookies}){
  my %cookie = %{$cookie_ref};
  my $name = $cookie{'name'};# - STRING
  my $value = $cookie{'value'};# - STRING
  my $path = $cookie{'path'};# - STRING
  my $domain = $cookie{'domain'};# - STRING
  my $secure = $cookie{'secure'};# - BOOLEAN

  print "Name: $name ";
  print "Value: $value ";
  print "Path: $path ";
  print "Domain: $domain ";
  print "Secure: $secure \n";

  $cookie_jar_obj->set_cookie(0, $name, $value
                             , $path, $domain, 443
                             , '', $secure, 14400000, 0
                    );
}



print "Cookies to be sent:\n";
print Dumper($cookie_jar_obj->get_cookies( ".myhost.com" ));

$ua->default_header('Accept' => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
$ua->default_header('Accept-Encoding' => "gzip, deflate, br");
$ua->default_header('Accept-Language' => "en-US,en;q=0.5");
$ua->default_header('Connection' => "keep-alive");
$ua->default_header('Host' => "www.example.com");
$ua->default_header('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' => "1");
$ua->default_header('User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0");

$ua->show_progress( 1 );

my $response = $ua->get($uri, ':content_file' => $tmp->filename);

print $response->status_line,"\n" if !$response->is_success;
print $tmp->filename . "\n";

<>;
$driver->get('https://example.com');
```

But I still get:

> 401 Unauthorized (9s)

Comment: You will need to compare what LWP::UserAgent sends with what your browser sends. Maybe the UA is different or some other fingerprint, or some other headers are missing.

Comment: @Corion I added all the headers that I can see in the firefox request. All the lines that start with: "$ua->default_header("

Comment: When you login manually how do you know which file to download? How do you know the correct URL?

Comment: @Andrey there are fixed ids when wich do not change.

Comment: If you know the URL, after you login you should be able to do $driver->get('https://example.com/myfile.tcx');

Comment: @Andrey, that works for the first file, but then it is stucked there. It seems as the driver waits for the website to load but is just downloaded in the browser and does not realize the connection was successful.